# JFrame AWT-EventQueue-0 error

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe

MyImg.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D; 
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;

public class MyImg {

    private BufferedImage img;
    private int x,y;

    public MyImg( String imageFileName, int x, int y)  {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        try{
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(imageFileName));

        } catch  (IOException e) {


        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
        g.drawImage(img, x, y, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), null);  
    }

}
```

Frametester.java

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


/**
   This program demonstrates how to install an action listener.
*/
public class FrameTester
{  
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        DrawImageTester theImgTester = new DrawImageTester(); 
        frame.add(theImgTester);


        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;
}
```

DrawImageTester.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D; 
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class DrawImageTester extends JComponent{
    private MyImg img1, img2;

    public DrawImageTester() {
        img1 = new MyImg(Definition.IMG_BG_BLACK, 100, 100 );
        img2 = new MyImg(Definition.IMG_BG_WHITE, 200, 100);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics h) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)h;

        img1.paint(g);  
        img2.paint(g);

    }
}
```

Definition.java

```
public class Definition{
    final public static String IMG_BG_BLACK = "image/black.PNG";
    final public static String IMG_BG_WHITE = "image/white.PNG";

    final public static String IMG_KNIGHT_BLACK = "image/bKn.png";
}
```

When I run FrameTester.java, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyImg.paint(MyImg.java:27)
    at DrawImageTester.paint(DrawImageTester.java:17)
```

The problem lies within this line:

```
public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.drawImage(img, x, y, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), null);  
}
```

I think this is caused by an object not being initialized. I am pretty sure img is initialized. img is declared in MyImg.java, the MyImg object is created in the DrawImageTester.java class. The DrawImageTester object is created inside main. Both x, and y, have values, and getWidth, and getHeight are methods of the BufferedImage class.
Can anyone lend me some help?

Comment: Your img variable is likely null, likely due to your File path being incorrect. Time to debug this. Note that it's better to use resources and not files to get images. Also, never leave a catch block empty.

Comment: `img` is `null`, you need to debug your code and find out why.

Comment: You're ignoring the most important piece of feedback which would tell WHY your code isn't working `try{ img = ImageIO.read(new File(imageFileName)); } catch  (IOException e) { }` <- Look and empty `catch` block!  Try putting `e.printStackTrace()` in there and see what happens

Comment: Alright, I added the e.printStackTrace() and I get the error: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
At this line:  img = ImageIO.read(new File(imageFileName));

Perhaps there's a problem changing from String to File?

Comment: I have my image folder in both my src, and bin folder in eclipse, I don't see how my file path is wrong.

Comment: Ooh I just figured it out. The working directory isn't in the scr nor the bin folder. I moved my image folder out and now its working.